# Is there a way to suppress the first page of my output pdf in latex and let the pdf start on the second page?

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to suppress the first page of my output pdf in latex and start on the second page?

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I follow: do you want to import an existing PDF file into your document, beginning with page 2? Or suppress the first page of your output?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to include an external pdf into your tex document? How do you want to include your file (`includepdf`, `includegraphics`, ...)?

Comment: I am trying to suppress the first page of my output.

Comment: But why are you trying to do this?  The first page is the most useful part of the document.  Are you trying to have a different first page?  What will it be?  How are you intending to create the final document with the different first page?  Or is there something else going on?

Comment: What exactly is on the first page? Is it a titlepage, for example created through the \make title command?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. Somehow my latex does not print the title page as my first page, but a blank page only with: 3.3.30Bsp.3.3.3 . I am not sure why latex does this,  I cheked whether I put something similar  before \begin{document}, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way is to use the `pagesel` package. In your preamble write:

```
\usepackage[2-:]{pagesel}
```

In the optional argument, the `2-:` means print pages 2 through the end of the document. Other options include giving a single number to print a single page, a range, e.g., `2-4`, or writing `-4` will be from the beginning through page 4. Multiple ranges can be specified, separated by commas, e.g., `3, 5-7, 14-:`.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** As inspired by Frank Mittelbach's comment below (but he has a typo in it), this can be simplified to:

```
\AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{\DiscardShipoutBox}
```

If you mean not outputting the first page that LaTeX generates to the PDF file, but only pages 2 and following:

```
\AddToHook{shipout/before}[nofirstpage]{\SkipFirstPage}
\newcommand\SkipFirstPage{\DiscardShipoutBox\RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[nofirstpage]}
```

You put both commands best before `\begin{document}`.
`\AddToHook` is a command that specifies that something has to be done at a specific point in the future, in this case just before a page is written to the PDF (or DVI) file. And in this case it specifies to throw away the page (`\DiscardShipoutBox`), and then not to do this on the following pages (by removing the hook code).

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know what: \AddtoHook is, I know that I have to put the second one before \begin{document}, but where do I put  \AddtoHook ?

Comment: I have added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: I was going to suggest putting the first page into a savebox.  I forgot that it already IS in a savebox.

Comment: Given that we know it is the "first" page we want to drop you can simply use \AddtoHookNext{shipout/before}{\DiscardShipoutBox}

Comment: @Sarah for \AddToHook  read `texdoc lthooks-doc` and `texdoc ltshipout-doc`